# SQL migration script - insert into select with output ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway, data-migration

I am using `PostgreSQL` and `Flyway` to perform a data migration in an application. The idea is to move rows from one table to another and keep the link between the old and new table in the old table. So, let's say we have **Table_1** with columns (id, name, user_id) and a new **Table_2** with similiar columns (id2, name2, user_id2).

Now, the first step will be to add a column to **Table_1** that will store the id of its counterpart in new Table_2. So:

```
alter Table_1 add column if not exists migrated_table_2_id int;
```

And now I would like to write an sql that will perform the migration of data from Table_1 to Table_2 and at the same time fill in the id values in the `migrated_table_2_id` column. So something like:

```
insert into Table_2 (name2, user_id2) select name, user_id from Table_1;
```

but with filling in the `migrated_table_2_id` with the newly created row in Table 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE, assuming that `name2`, `user_id2` or both in combination are unique:

```
with i as (
      insert into Table_2 (name2, user_id2)
          select name, user_id 
          from Table_1
          returning *
     )
update table_1 t1
    set t1.user_id2 = t2.id
    from table_2 t2
    where t2.name = t1.name and t2.user_id2 = t.user_id;
```